# how can we share login between different domains (not sub-domain)

Tags: session, cookies, web

How can we share same login with different domains. For example, if there are 2 different domanins www.abc.com and www.xyz.com, can we login in one website and other will recognize it(when we refresh) ?

How to manage cookies/session for such case ?

Like how gmail and youtube manages it. If we login in gmail (which is accounts.google.com), youtube recognizes this. So exactly how do they manage ?

Answer (score 0):

Google uses OAuth 2.0 for SSO.

You can read more about this here ... https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: this is related to implementing Google login within a website. but if we want to implement our own login mechanism for sso, how can we achieve between different domains.